# How to POST JSON data from Flash (AS2) with the JSON as the body of the request

Tags: flash, json, actionscript-2

All,

I'm working on a Flash AS2 application that needs to post JSON data to a web service.

In previous projects, I've used LoadVars.send() or LoadVars.sendAndLoad() successfully to manage this:

```
var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
send_lv.data = JSON.stringify({some json object});

var response_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
response_lv.onData = function(rawdata) {
    var o:Object = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    ....
}

send_lv.sendAndLoad("somepage.php", response_lv, "POST");
```

In somepage.php, I can grab that JSON data using $_POST['data'].

However, on this project, the developer of the web service requires the JSON content to be the BODY of the request (i.e., not a name/value pair). Is this possible with LoadVars?

If not, is there another way to do this with AS2?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry... This is the second time this month I'm answering my own question. However, it's the best I've got so far...

Long story short... with LoadVars(), you can POST a series of name/value pairs to a URL. But the developer of the specific service I'm sending data to has specifically asked that, instead of using name/value pairs, the data IS the body of the post.

I couldn't figure out how to do that with LoadVars().

However, it looks like I CAN do that with XML.sendAndLoad(), even though the data I'm sending ISN'T actually XML (In my case, it's JSON).

For example, if the JSON is stored in an object named json:

```
dataAsString = JSON.stringify(json);
var send_xml:XML = new XML(dataAsString);
var response_xml:XML = new XML()
response_xml.onData = function(rawResponseData) {
    trace (rawResponseData);
}
send_xml.sendAndLoad([url], response_xml, "POST");
```

If the [url] is "somepage.php", then, in the PHP page, you can get the data like this:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    // data will contain now contain the json object as a string
?>
```

I can't imagine this is the only (or best) way to do this. For example, send_xml isn't a valid XML object (since the json string obviously won't be valid XML).

Nevertheless, this allows me to post the JSON string to a service without using a name/value pair.

Comment: did you compile your project with adobe flash professional? it freezes an swf compiled with mtasc, however it seems the only option

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic, but the best solution I found, which also works with PUT (via X-HTTP-Method-Override) is to derive a new class from LoadVars, as described by jadent here:
[Sending JSON in ActionScript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234542/sending-json-in-actionscript-2)

```
class LoadJson extends LoadVars {
    public var json:String;

    public function toString() {
        return json;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do something like this:

```
var lj:LoadJson = new LoadJson();
lj.json = {"key":"value"};
lj.onLoad = function(success:Boolean):Void { trace(success); };
lj.addRequestHeader(["X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT"]);
lj.sendAndLoad("http://yoururl.com", lj, "POST");
```

Took me 3 days to find that -.-

Answer (score 0):

Florian Lightning's answer is correct (thank you for posting).

If you want to use the suggested `LoadJson` class as a substitute for `LoadVars` project-wide (where it would likely handle `GET` requests) `toString()` should return its super if no json payload is detected.

```
class LoadJson extends LoadVars {

    public var json:String;

    public function toString() {
        if (json != undefined) {
            return json;
        }
        return super.toString();
    }

}
```